# Why are these datagridview not populating from a MySql datasource?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

Following the example for master/detail relationship on the MS site, between two `datagridviews` I run into a problem with them not populating, however on reverting to unrelated tables to simplify the scenario - I find them still not populating. Why?

Username/password is fine, the connection is working as evidenced clearly in the IDE watch window etc.

The commented out block in the centre was just for testing, after blocking out the relationship aspects, but I run into a further issue with an exception—namely —`System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` does not contain a definition for `DataBind` and no extension method `DataBind` accepting a first argument of type `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061)

```
    private void GetData()
    {

        //example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y8c0cxey.aspx
        try
        {
            // Specify a connection string. Replace the given value with a  
            // valid connection string for a Northwind SQL Server sample 
            // database accessible to your system.
            String connectionString = "SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=infomod;UID=xxxxxx;PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx;";
            MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

//          connection.Open();

            // Create a DataSet.
            DataSet data = new DataSet();
            data.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

            // Add data from the Customers table to the DataSet.
            MySqlDataAdapter masterDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("Select ProjectId, Name from projects", connection);

            masterDataAdapter.Fill(data, "projects");

//              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
//              masterDataAdapter.Fill(dt);
//              dataGridViewProjects.DataSource= dt;
//              dataGridViewProjects.DataBind();

            // Add data from the Orders table to the DataSet.
            MySqlDataAdapter detailsDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("select InputDocID,DocName,ProjectID from inputdocs", connection);
            detailsDataAdapter.Fill(data, "inputdocs");

            // Establish a relationship between the two tables.
            DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("ProjectsInputDocs",
                data.Tables["projects"].Columns["ProjectID"],
                data.Tables["inputdocs"].Columns["ProjectID"]);
            data.Relations.Add(relation);

            // Bind the master data connector to the Customers table.
            bindingSourceProject.DataSource = data;
            bindingSourceProject.DataMember = "projects";



            // Bind the details data connector to the master data connector, 
            // using the DataRelation name to filter the information in the  
            // details table based on the current row in the master table. 
            bindingSourceInputDocs.DataSource = bindingSourceProject;
            bindingSourceInputDocs.DataMember = "ProjectsInputDocs";

        }
        catch (MySqlException crap)
        {
            OutCrap(crap);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using a Bindingsource seems to be the issue - not sure what I am doing wrong, but if I leave it out of the equation, using the MySqlAdapter for filling a datatable and assigning that to the datasource there is no issue. I had hoped to use  a binding source however to take care of the synchro with master/detail relationship. So still with hope somebody can illuminate matters!

Comment: Does this link help? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e6698cad-15f7-41e7-82c3-cc71c17f30e2/datagridview-no-databind?forum=csharpgeneral

I might be a bit confused about the issue with all the commented out bits in your code :)